# Как можно вывести простое JSON-сообщение в Spring-app

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

Пишу приложение на Spring-MVC. Возникла необходимость, чтобы при выполнении метода выводилось сообщение.

Следующий метод из класса типа Serive:

```
// Отменить заказ
public void cancelOrder(Long id){
    Order order = orderRepository.getById(id);
    order.setOrderStatus(false); // Добавим JSON сообщение, что заказ отменен.
    orderRepository.save(order);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например:

```
@RestController
public class Foo {
    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public String greeting() {
        return "{" +
                "\"orderNumber\": 123,\n" +
                "\"orderStatus\": \"canceled\"\n" +
                "}";
    }
}
```

В браузере (http://localhost:8080/foo) увидите:

```
{ "orderNumber": 123, "orderStatus": "canceled" }
```

[Пример rest сервиса](https://spring-projects.ru/guides/rest-service/)